# Grafana Connect HTTP URL data source

Tags: http, grafana

How can I use a data source that is just a plain HTTP data source?  I.e. https://cnlohr.com/data_sources/ccu_test where it's just a number?

I could potentially wrap it in JSON, but I can't find any basic JSON, REST, or raw HTTP data source for Grafana Connect.

Comment: I tried using CSV Data source https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-csv-datasource/ , but it always errors when trying to set it as a recorded query with "Result: Internal Server Error"

Comment: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/?search=json

Comment: The data was already available from another source in the raw mode. Wrapping in JSON would have required me to make my server wrap it.  Using just a number was a lot cleaner way.

Comment: Additionally, both JSON Plugins (JSON API and JSON) error out with "JSON API: Bad Request"  The CSV plugin was much more helpful with its errors.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Apparently the CSV Plugin here DOES work.  I just had to re-create it a few times to get around the internal server error: https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-csv-datasource/

Once added to your system, add it as a new integration/connection.  Be sure to make each query only output one number (you will need multiple queries, one for each column).  Then you can save each as a recorded query.